# Make BOOTCAMP partition active/bootable on Snow Leopard

Tags: macos, boot, boot-camp

I upgraded my main hard drive which had a bootcamp partition on it.  I made a DMG of the boot camp partition and then later restored it on a new partition (on the new drive) using Boot Camp Assistant.

Now all of the files are there but it is not bootable.  When I press Option upon boot, I'm only presented with my main partition.

I followed the instructions here: http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?messageID=10835653

which basically said, use fdisk to flag the partition as bootable, but it seemed to have no effect.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you run the Boot Camp Assistant to create a Windows partition for you and then restore it, or did you just resize the Mac OS X partition manually and restore?

Comment: I used Bootcamp Assistant to create the partition, then I restored the DMG on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the partition seen when you open the Startup Disk preference pane under System Preferences?

Comment: Nope.  Just lists my main drive/partition (and a network startup option).

Comment: Actually re-selecting the drive as the startup disk fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, IMHO fastest and painless way

I see only one working scenario:

1. Put your old hard drive back
2. Make sure its still working windows and mac side
3. Use Winclone software on mac side to clone your windows partition to external drive
4. replace old hard drive with new one
5. Install winclone software to mac side
6. restore Windows partition from external drive to bootcamp partition what you already created

Comment: Unfortunately I already formatted the old drive :(

Answer (score 0):

How large did you make the Boot Camp partition? If it's larger than 32GB and is formatted as FAT32, then you cannot restore the Windows OS to it because that's the limit of the filesystem. You can use the Windows install disc to format the Boot Camp partition to NTFS, but be careful that you don't erase your Mac partition.